# VB syntax for response.addheader

Tags: asp-classic, redirect

i'm placing a automatic redirect on my Classic ASP page (vb). i want to call the url from a variable (url2) versus hardcoding it. just need to know what the right syntax is. this is my current code:

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH","10;URL=url2")
```

Comment: Which version of VB?  Is this ASP.NET or Classic ASP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP-Classic/VBScipt:-

```
Response.AddHeader "Refresh", "10;url=" & strUrl
```

You don't use ( ) when calling methods from which you do not accept a return value.

Comment: i need it to call a variable as the url.

Comment: actually, in my case i did need the () brackets for my code to run correctly but you put me on the right track. thanks!
Response.AddHeader ("Refresh", "10;url=" & url2)

Comment: @MG: Your question indicates you are using Classic ASP, so the only reason you would use brackets here is if you are using JScript as your script language, the brackets in VBScript would be a syntax error. In JScript you would not use & for string concatenation but + instead.

Answer (score 1):

The refresh header is not officially standardised. This means every browser may implement it differently. I'd recommend using normal HTTP casing, like the following:

```
Response.AddHeader "Refresh", "10; url=" & url2
```

[Edited to reflect new information from poster]

Otherwise there doesn't seem to be an issue, although if it doesn't still work I'd suspect ASP.NET may strip out the header some place else for its own purposes.

Comment: Which browsers implement it differently?

Comment: There is no standard implementation, so how they do choose to implement it is completely in the air. It is entirely possible that most modern browsers use exactly the same implementation, but that would be impossible to verify since there's no 'correct' implementation to test against.

Comment: (hmm) ok, I can't think of too many different ways to implement wait for x amount of time then navigate to y.  To do so that it actually makes a difference to anyone would be quite a feat.

Comment: I can think of quite a few ways, having worked on the source code for a couple of browsers. Primarily, what headers do you choose to keep when you do redirect? How do you inform the user you are redirecting? How you do inform Javascript's inherent objects of the change? What DOM events are triggered (inc. bespoke)? I'm sure for 99% of purposes though, the difference would be moot though.

Comment: Just to add to that list (because it's an interesting question): What do you do with malformed input? What defines malformed input? Which, if any, of the existing markup/scripts do you evaluate?